# Multiple Linear Regression, Categorical and Numeric Independent Variables

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I have a dataset with multiple months of data (over 1,000s of records), which is structured:

```
   Patient_fin      DOV            Acuity     Wait_time
       1            1/1/2019         1            345
       2            1/1/2019         2            402
       3            1/1/2019         4            49
       4            1/1/2019         1            334
       5            1/2/2019         3            268
```

I want to develop a linear regression model where the output can be interpreted as, for example (assuming significance), on a day when the patient volume is 300, we can expect the wait time for acuity 4 patients to be 19 minutes more than the acuity 3 patients (which is the reference group).

I wrote the code to create a dummy variables for the categorical acuity variable.

```
 data test1;
 set test; 
 if pt_acuity ~= '' then pt_acuity1=0; 
 if pt_acuity ~= '' then pt_acuity2=0; 
 ...
 if pt_acuity = '1 - Resuscitation'  then pt_acuity1=1; 
 if pt_acuity = '2 - Emergent'       then pt_acuity2=1; 
 ...
 run;
```

Now this is where I'm not seeing things clearly.

I could be looking at this all wrong but...

How can I create a table for my model which includes a variable for the volume per day, and the median wait times by acuity?

[image]

I tried Proc Tab but the variables are not in the correct format to be analyzed.

```
 proc tabulate data = test out=test1;
 class  DOV Acuity;
 var Wait_time;
 table DOV , Wait_time* Acuity*(Median)
 all='TOTAL'*(n*f=6.0)/rts=25 misstext='0' printmiss;;
 run;
```

[image]

Comment: PROC MEANS should be what you use to summarize the data but I'd hesitate to model summarized data. What type of model are you planning to use, PROC AUTOREG I assuem

Comment: @Reeza I agree with not modeling summarized data; however, I'm still trying to wrap my head around structuring a code that will produce the desired output. I'm honestly not too familiar with AUTOREG and am reading up on it now. Thanks!

Comment: You will need arrays at minimum. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/

Comment: This is time to event analysis, so I feel you should be using survival analysis instead. Especially because people check in and then can leave instead of being seen. This also involves total caseload so also a queuing theory problem so not a trivial analysis by any means. I'd probably simulate the system and see what happens personally. FYI - most of the procs you'll be working with can deal with the categorical variables you won't need to create the dummy variables yourself.

Comment: @Reeza thanks for the continued insight - in regards to the survival analysis, I a priori removed patients without a wait time.

Comment: That's not good though, because that number will likely change your results. Someone waiting and leaving is almost more problematic because you're likely to miss cases and its going to be worse during high peak periods as people don't always wait. You can't ignore it.

Comment: Understood, we have very low rates of left without being seen, regardless of season. Nonetheless, your point is duly noted. Thank you.